# C string literals linking

Tags: c, string, linker

As far as I am aware, the linker tries to *merge* two string literals into one single literal, if they are both the same, e.g.:

file1.c

```
char const* firstString = "foo";
```

file2.c

```
char const* secondString = "foo";
```

Would result in only one occurence of `foo\0` in the respective memory section (saving 4 Bytes). This is especially important for embedded applications (how does `avr-gcc` vs. `gcc` behave).

But I was wondering if I can actually count on this to happen, and rely, that if two strings are equal, also their pointers are equal (provided that in the whole program, you only pass string literals around and no runtime generated strings exist -- which is a reasonable assumption in my case). Obviously, I want to speed up speed comparisons with this, and allow a commonly used function to receive a string literal like so:

```
void lock(char const*);
void unlock(char const*);

lock("test");
dosmth();
unlock("test");
```

In essence, I want to avoid having a huge enum and huge switches inside the `lock`/`unlock` functions.

Comment: The C standard gives no such guarantees

Comment: Note: I modified the question to reflect that all strings are immutable.

Comment: Using strings for this purpose is beyond broken.

Comment: @R..: This is a very very simplified example, and a mere thought whether it could be done. But perhaps you might care to elaborate on your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker doesn't have to merge anything.  It just has to map a declared type to a defined type.  That involves finding the defined type and filling out the address offsets to jump to the right item.

What you are talking about would be an optimizing linker.  Many linkers don't optimize at all, and those that do aren't held to an optimizing standard, so you'll never be able to generalize beyond the observed findings for the linker you discover (on that machine, at that time).

Answer (score 3):

Actually they **can't** point to the same memory, since you can write to them.

Now, if you were to say:

```
char *s1 = "MyString";
char *s2 = "MyString";
```

then indeed it is *possible* that `s1 == s2`. Don't think it's guaranteed.

Comment: They should be constant strings, shouldn't they? -- Even I throw them in a `char []` variable; The literals themselves are `const`.

Comment: Nope only char *str = ... is constant. When you do initialization as you did the string is mutable.

Comment: If I think about it, you're right, it should be `const char*` or `const char[]`.

Comment: Should be the first one. 2nd one is always mutable memory as it explicitly reserves memory.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably not count on it as it is compiler dependent on how symbols get resolved like this. Most compilers create 1 instance of the constant string and then simply reference that but I would not depend on this as there are cases when this does not work. Personally I wouldn't use strings like that in your lock and unlock method. An enum will probably serve you better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the wrong track. Not only that the linker doesn't merge string literals from different compilation units, it most probably doesn't even create an external symbol for them at all.

Even inside the same compilation unit, the compiler *may* merge two occurrences of the same string literal into one, but it is not obliged to do so:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the  appropriate values.

Now to the real problem that seems to be at the source of your question. Doing lock/unlock pairs based on string literals is probably not a good idea in C. As you say this has the tendency to bloat your code with `switch` or similar stuff.

More natural would be to have a lock type and to declare a global variable with a distinguishable name for each of your distinctive lock/unlock events. This forces you to declare each such event in a way that is visible in all your compilation units, and to pick out one compilation unit where you actually define it.